# Is there any code example of data imputation by VAE or SDA by using deeplearning4j

Tags: deeplearning4j

I am trying to impute images, like:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/284476380_Variational_Auto-encoded_Deep_Gaussian_Processes

The example of mnist image imputation.

How to do it by using deeplearning4j VAE or SDA?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a DL4J example of a variational autoencoder (VAE) https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/tree/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/unsupervised/variational

All Deeplearning4j and DataVec/ETL examples can be found here:

https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/

Please join our developer community on Gitter if you have more questions:

https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j

Comment: I've go thru almost all the example of DL4J and study the example of VAE and SDA as well. I am a beginner of deeplearning, just do know how to do image imputation (2D data) by VAE/SDA using DL4j. Just saw a couple of papers about this, but do know how to implement them using java